# Pandas create new columns by extracting specific elements from string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a time series dataframe that contains the evolution of a price over time, and I use a column called `high_low` to store the list of the last high/low prices that were detected.

It's possible to have up to 10 last high/low prices in this `high_low` column.

I would like to generate 3 new columns `past_hl_3`, `past_hl2` and `past_hl1`, that will contains the values of the 3 most recent `high_low` prices (so the 3 upmost right elements of the string).

Starting data :

```
    date         price   high_low
0   2021-04-01   10      NaN
1   2021-04-02   12      NaN
2   2021-04-03   14      NaN
3   2021-04-04   13      "14"
4   2021-04-05    9      "14"
5   2021-04-06   16      "14 9"
6   2021-04-07   15      "14 9 16"
7   2021-04-08   14      "14 9 16"   
8   2021-04-09   13      "14 9 16"
9   2021-04-10   12      "14 9 16"
10  2021-04-11   18      "14 9 16 12"
11  2021-04-12   19      "14 9 16 12"
12  2021-04-13   22      "14 9 16 12"
13  2021-04-14   25      "14 9 16 12"
```

Expected data :

```
    date         price   high_low      price_hl_3  price_hl2  price_hl1
0   2021-04-01   10      NaN           NaN         NaN        NaN
1   2021-04-02   12      NaN           NaN         NaN        NaN
2   2021-04-03   14      NaN           NaN         NaN        NaN
3   2021-04-04   13      "14"          NaN         NaN         14
4   2021-04-05    9      "14"          NaN         NaN         14
5   2021-04-06   16      "14 9"        NaN          14          9
6   2021-04-07   15      "14 9 16"     14            9         16
7   2021-04-08   14      "14 9 16"     14            9         16
8   2021-04-09   13      "14 9 16"     14            9         16
9   2021-04-10   12      "14 9 16"     14            9         16
10  2021-04-11   18      "14 9 16 12"   9           16         12   
11  2021-04-12   19      "14 9 16 12"   9           16         12
12  2021-04-13   22      "14 9 16 12"   9           16         12
13  2021-04-14   25      "14 9 16 12"   9           16         12
```

I was thinking using something like that, but it's not working, plus I would also need to convert the values back to integers anyway:

```
df['price_hl_3'] = np.where(len(df.high_low.str.split()) >= 3, df.high_low.str.split()[-3], np.nan)
df['price_hl_2'] = np.where(len(df.high_low.str.split()) >= 2, df.high_low.str.split()[-2], np.nan)
df['price_hl_1'] = np.where(len(df.high_low.str.split()) >= 1, df.high_low.str.split()[-1], np.nan)
```

I'm sure there is an easy way to reach the expected result, but I can't seems to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the following function to get the content of 3 new columns
from *high_low* field in the current row, split into a list:

```
def getElems(lst):
    rv = lst[-3:][::-1] if isinstance(lst, list) else []
    rv += [np.nan] * (3 - len(rv))
    return pd.Series(rv[::-1], index=['price_hl3', 'price_hl2', 'price_hl1'])
```

Then run:

```
result = df.join(df.high_low.str.split().apply(getElems))
```

The result is:

```
          date  price    high_low price_hl3 price_hl2 price_hl1
0   2021-04-01     10         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1   2021-04-02     12         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2   2021-04-03     14         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
3   2021-04-04     13          14       NaN       NaN        14
4   2021-04-05      9          14       NaN       NaN        14
5   2021-04-06     16        14 9       NaN        14         9
6   2021-04-07     15     14 9 16        14         9        16
7   2021-04-08     14     14 9 16        14         9        16
8   2021-04-09     13     14 9 16        14         9        16
9   2021-04-10     12     14 9 16        14         9        16
10  2021-04-11     18  14 9 16 12         9        16        12
11  2021-04-12     19  14 9 16 12         9        16        12
12  2021-04-13     22  14 9 16 12         9        16        12
13  2021-04-14     25  14 9 16 12         9        16        12
```

Note that the type of all 3 new columns is *object* and non-NaN
elements are **strings**.

Initially I thought about converting them to *int*, but *Pandas* has
such an awkward characteristics that if a column contains both *int*
elements and *NaN* (which is a "special case" of *float*) then the
whole column is coerced to *float*.

## An alternative to get *int* values

Recent versions of *Pandas* include *convert_dtypes()* method, to change
the type of each column to *best possible dtypes using dtypes supporting pd.NA*.

So you can run:

```
result = df.join(df.high_low.str.split().apply(getElems)).convert_dtypes()
```

and then all 3 new columns (and additionally also *price*) are converted to
**Int64** (note capital *'I'* in the type name).

Print the *result* to see the difference.

This time instead of *NaN* new columns contain *<NA>* (another
representation of a "missing" value) and other values are just **integers**.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `split` then `sorted`

```
df['high_low'] = df['high_low'].str.strip('"')
df = df.join(df['high_low'].str.split(' ',expand=True).\
         apply(lambda x : pd.Series(sorted(x,key=pd.notnull)),1)).iloc[:,1:]
df
Out[157]: 
    price    high_low     0     1     2    3
0      10         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
1      12         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
2      14         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
3      13          14  None  None  None   14
4       9          14  None  None  None   14
5      16        14 9  None  None    14    9
6      15     14 9 16  None    14     9   16
7      14     14 9 16  None    14     9   16
8      13     14 9 16  None    14     9   16
9      12     14 9 16  None    14     9   16
10     18  14 9 16 12    14     9    16   12
11     19  14 9 16 12    14     9    16   12
12     22  14 9 16 12    14     9    16   12
13     25  14 9 16 12    14     9    16   12
```